# Properties of a mysterious celestial body that creates a permanent eclipse on earth

Tags: astrophysics, eclipses

Sometime in the near future, a strange heavenly body appears in the skies of Earth. Unbeknownst to everyone, it's actually the egg of a horrific, unimaginable cosmic entity, traveling through space and time to find a planet harboring life.

This cosmic egg needs to create a permanent state of darkness on earth but through a series of circumstances, it's only able to block off a certain portion of the sun.

When you look up at the sky, this is the closest visual approximation of what you would see: [image]

So what I'm looking for is mainly two things:
- the size of this object
- the approximate distance it would have to be from the planet

I'm handwaving the actual possibility of such an object existing because, well, it's just one of cthulhus cousins come to say hello. I'm more concerned with its physics properties, so how big and how far away from the earth would the Egg have to be to achieve the closest result to the picture I posted above?

Comment: Does its shadow need to (almost) completely cover the entire planet, or only a specific area of it?

Comment: @Cadence For the purposes of the story I'd like it to cover almost the entire planet

Comment: Very related recent question: https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/173845/54187

Answer (score 5):

Think of a trapezoid. The shorter parallel side is Earth's diameter, ~6,400 km. The longer parallel side is the Sun's diameter, ~696,000 km. The distance between the two sides is the distance between the two bodies, ~150,000,000 km. (All of these numbers are very generously rounded, and assume both bodies are perfectly spherical, which they aren't. However, it'll do for a rough estimate.) Note that this is a very narrow trapezoid, over 200 times as long in one direction as the other. That's good, because it minimizes the effects of the actual shapes of the bodies in question.

The legs of the trapezoid are the lines of sight from the furthest extent of the Earth in the same direction, to the furthest extent of the Sun in the same direction. The diagonals of the trapezoid are the lines of sight to the opposite edge of the Sun. If your object is large enough to occlude all four lines of sight, there won't be any part of the Sun visible from the Earth.

The minimum diameter of the mysterious object is the distance across all four lines of sight at its orbital distance - or, to go back to the diagram, it's the length of a line running across the trapezoid. This length is linearly interpolated between the two parallel sides. If the line is halfway in between the two side, its length is halfway between theirs. If it's a quarter of the way between them, it's a quarter of the way between sizes. Etc.

If we follow @RollTime's suggestion to place the object at the Earth-Sun L1 point - which isn't totally stable, but is close enough - it will be about 1,500,000 km away from the Earth. (From the center of the Earth, technically, not that it makes a huge difference.) Conveniently, that's about 1% of the distance, so its diameter is equal to the Earth's diameter, plus 1% of the difference: 6,400 km + 1% * 689,600 km = about 13,300 km.

So, to put a "cosmic egg" at the Earth-Sun L1 such that the Sun is virtually invisible around its edges, its diameter needs to be about twice that of the Earth. This is a bit of a problem, because if its mass is more than about 1% of the Earth's, it will not stay stable at the L1 point because it will deflect the Earth's orbit too much.

If it's also mostly spherical and has the same density as Earth, it will mass about 4x Earths - 400 times too much. So, it needs to be no more than 1/400th as dense as Earth, which works out to 0.014 g/cc - less than a sixth the density of hydrogen gas. That's not *impossible* (it could be a hollow shell, for instance) but it implies a very specific construction and/or materials. Alternatively, it could be a thin disc instead of a spheroid, and have a more normal density. Another structure would mimic some solar-sail-type spacecraft proposals, with a very large, very thin "sail" to catch light and a compact "core" where the actual egg is located.

TL;DR: The "cosmic egg" will be about 13,300 kilometers across, mass no more than the neighborhood of 10^22 kilograms - which implies that it's *extremely* rarified or very thin - and will orbit about 1,500,000 km above Earth, on a line directly between it and the Sun.

Comment: And if it's hollow, Terran tidal forces between the egg's nearer and farther surfaces will [tear it apart](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/173845/how-close-an-orbit-could-you-get-to-earth-with-a-planet-sized-object-ship-withou#comment540995_173854).

Comment: @Michael Tidal forces fall off with the cube of the orbital distance. It's at ~4 times the moon's orbital distance, so its tidal stresses would be ~1/64th as intense.

Answer (score 2):

You could put it at [L1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_point). Any object there will hold its relative positions between the Earth and Sun. It's right around a million miles from earth. Be aware, of course, that any entity large enough to block out a large portion of Earth's sky would also probably be massive enough to shift Earth's orbit. I'm unsure of the exact size, but *very* large, obviously.

Comment: The L1 point is an unstable equilibrium as well; even if its mass was insignificant compared to the Earth's (egg is very, very light for its size?), it'd need to be able to adjust its own motion slightly to stop it from drifting.

Answer (score 2):

> This cosmic egg needs to create a permanent state of darkness on earth
>
> so how big and how far away from the earth would the Egg have to be to achieve the closest result to the picture I posted above?

From elementary geometry consideration, if you want that to be visible on all of Earth surface, your egg has to cover the very surface of the Sun facing toward Earth. In any other combination of size and distances there would be places in which the visual effect would be visible and places in which the effect wouldn't be visible. In other words, they won't be in darkness.

---

To put this in mathematical terms, in order to plunge the *entire* Earth into darkness, the object's minimum diameter must be $D_{egg} = (d)D_{Earth} + (1 - d)D_{Sun}$, where $D_{Earth}$, $D_{Sun}$ are the diameters of the Earth and Sun, and $d$ is the proportional distance of the object between the two (i.e the distance between the egg and the Sun divided by 1 AU). However you may get some leakage at the minimum theoretical diameter.

Note that solar eclipses work with the much smaller Luna because only a small portion of Earth sees a total eclipse.